# ViewBag SelectList not setting selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my view I have:

```
<tr class="form-group">
    <th><label class="control-label">Technician</label></th>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TechnicianID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID)
    </td>
</tr>
```

And in my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id) {
        var salescall = (id != null) ? db.SalesCalls.Find(id) : new SalesCall();

        if (salescall == null) {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ViewBag.CompanyID = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "Name", salescall.CompanyID);
        var technicians = db.UserProfiles.Select(t => new {
            ID = t.ID,
            Name = t.FirstName + " " + t.LastName,
        }).OrderBy(t => t.Name);
        var techID = CurrentUser.UserID(User);
        ViewBag.TechnicianID = new SelectList(technicians, "ID", "Name", techID);

        return View(salescall);
    }
```

When I debug, the value being passed to techID is the correct value, and that value does exist in the dropdown, but for some reason it is not being selected. How can I make this work?

Comment: Make sure there is no extra space at the end of the value for `techID` or the respective value in the dropdown. Use `trim()` to trail off any extra character that might have stored in the database.

Comment: @DennisR The value being passed is of the integer type. Also, when I manually enter the number instead of passing it through the techID variable, it still does not work. E.g. ViewBag.TechnicianID = new SelectList(technicians, "ID", "Name", 38);

Comment: Ok, Can you comment out the line `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID)` and see what happens with your original code?

Comment: @DennisR Yes, there was no difference.

Comment: Also make sure you don't have any name conflict else where in the view for `UserID` like `ViewBag.UserID`. Refer my other post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921984/dropdownlistfor-default-selected-item-from-model/25922369#25922369) for similar issue

Comment: @DennisR There are no conflicts with names that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ID = t.ID,
new SelectList(technicians, "ID", "Name", techID);
```

To

```
Id = t.ID,
new SelectList(technicians, "Id", "Name", techID);
```

My hunch is you are defining `Id` in the `User` model. It should have `Id` and `Name`.

EDIT

If `techID` is an integer, make sure you pass in an anonymous object:

```
new SelectList(technicians, "Id", "Name", new { Id = techID });
```